# Create jQuery Dialog on the fly

Tags: jquery, dialog, non-modal

Currently I have working code that creates some select and checkbox objects and overlays these over the current document. However this is a bad solution and I need to make it a non modal dialog box instead so that it is easier to read and can be moved around. I've looked at the demos over at jqueryui.com but when I copy the source code I can't even get it to display a dialog so I guess I'm missing something.

The values in the 'chooser' var are fixed. After a user chooses one of these values I create the set of checkboxes based on the choice. When a checkbox is checked or unchecked the code will perform some action (not shown here). How can I get the select set and checkboxes into a non modal jQuery dialog object instead and display it to the user until they decide to close it? Apart from the below objects the only other thing it needs is the ability to be minimized and closed.

```
var chooser = '<select class="criteria" id="criteria">' +
'<option value="Value 1">Value 1</option>' +
'<option value="Value 2">Value 2</option>' +
'</select>';

jQuery('.myClassName').addClass('my-chooser').append(
'<div class="criteria-chooser" id="criteria-chooser"></div>');
jQuery('.criteria-chooser').append(chooser);

jQuery('.criteria-chooser').append('<div class="criteria-choices" id="criteria-choices"></div>');
jQuery('.criteria-choices').append('<br>');
for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {
    jQuery('.criteria-choices').append('<tr>' +
    '<td><input type="checkbox" checked class="criteria-checkbox" id="' + i +
    '"></td>' +
    '<td> ' + arrayValue[i] + '</td>' +
    '</tr>');
}
```

Comment: The demos at jQueryUI.com will require you to be using jQueryUI; they won't work if you're only using jQuery by itself.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5355178/jquery-ui-dialog-on-the-fly-without-div might help.

Comment: Ok thanks Greg, at least that explains it.Can you recommend any other sites that have jQuery dialog examples?

Comment: I am making progress but have discovered that some of the objects I already have on the screen were causing the dialog box to stay in the background. I lowered the z-index values I was using on these other objects and found this fixed the problem.

Does anybody know of a way to make sure the dialog box is always on top? If the dialog does have a z-index value what is it so that I can ensure my other objects appear underneath it rather than above it.

Comment: The default `z-index` value of the dialog boxes is 1001. You can ensure they are always on top by setting the `zIndex` value of the dialog box to `9999` in the dialog box parameters when creating it.