# Load Modal dialog by injecting HTML with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following function on my JS file that has defined the HTML code for a Modal dialog that is defined in [here](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#modals)

I've copied the HTML code and assigned into a variable on my JS function:

```
function loadModalDialog(p1) {

     var modal =     '<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">' +
                    '   <div class="modal-header">' +
                    '       <button type="button" class="close" data- dismiss="modal" aria- hidden="true" >×</button>' +
                    '       <h3 id= "myModalLabel"> Modal header </h3>' +
                    '   </div>' +
                    '   <div class="modal-body">' +
                    '       <p>One fine body…</p>' +
                    '   </div>' +
                    '   <div class="modal-footer">' +
                    '       <button class="btn" data- dismiss="modal" aria- hidden="true"> Close </button>' +
                    '       <button class="btn btn-primary"> Save changes </button>' +
                    '   </div>' +
                    '</div>';  


}
```

Also, I have another JS function that calls loadModalDialog but at this point I am not sure how to inject the html that I have on my modal var into the DOM once I am inside of above function so I can display the modal dialog.

BTW, I want to inject the html through the JS function because eventually I will change the body of the dialog and it will change dynamically according p1 value.

BTW, the line of code that is calling loadModalDialog looks like this:

```
<a href="" role="button" onClick=loadModalDialog("' + p1 + '") data-toggle="modal">PopUp</a>
```

Any idea how it should work?

Answer (score 0):

Might be an approach. The trick is to establish a proper selector to wich the dialog() function could be called:

```
$("<div>Sample of an injected dialog</div>").dialog();
```

Is't actually very easy if you watch the jquery sample in contrast

```
$( "#dialog" ).dialog();
```

You simply replace the selector with concrete text (no meta chars).

If you want to execute a js function right after the dialog has loaded, you inline that function and provide it's parameters via JSON stringification. Like this

```
$("<div id='difflv2d'></div><script>drawGraph("
  + JSON.stringify(sd.side) + "," + JSON.stringify(sd.id) + ","
  + JSON.stringify(sd.title) + "," + JSON.stringify(sd.num) + ","
  + JSON.stringify(sd.data) + ")</script>").dialog();
```

In the sample above, the drawing function selects the div given by id 'difflv2d' and puts its stuff onto it. Since the div already is part of the dialog (just loaded), the graphic appears on that dialog. Stuff to draw is read out of the variables provided properly.

Here is a reference: [on the fly div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5355178/jquery-ui-dialog-on-the-fly-without-div)