# Xslt jqueryui unused div

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui, xslt

First a warning, I'm an extreme noob to xslt so please excuse if this is a very stupid question.

I have a div like this,

`<div id="objectLocked"> This object is locked by another user. Do you want to remove the lock?</div>`

created inside a xsl:template, to be used in a jqueryui dialog, like this,

`$(function() {
                <xsl:if test="abc:hastext($activeschemadeflockedby) and not($activeschemadeflockedby=$currentuserdn)">
                $( '#objectLocked' ).dialog({
                autoOpen: true,
                buttons: [
                {
                text: "Yes",
                click: function()
                {
                updateLockedby();
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
                },
                {
                text: "No",
                click: function()
                {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
                } ],
                title: "Object locked",
                model: true
                });
              </xsl:if>`

The problem is that if the div has not been used (the if-test is false) the text "This object is ..." is displayed on the form".

What can I do to avoid it from being displayed?

Cheers

Harry

Answer (score 0):

There was no need for an explicit  defined, just used a solution found in this question: [Jquery-UI Dialog - on the fly without DIV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5355178/jquery-ui-dialog-on-the-fly-without-div)